# Can I use multiple SQLite databases with my Adobe Air application?

Tags: air, sqlite

I am developing an Air application.

Can I use multiple SQLite databases with my Adobe Air application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html) implies that yes you can:

> A SQLConnection instance is used to manage the creation of and
>   connection to local SQL **database files** (local **databases**).

Comment: The critical thing is going to be keeping in mind which database you're doing which query against. Get that straight and everything else should be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Donal Fellows, there is one caveat to this which doesn't appear to bubble to the forefront - but is actually part of the SQLite spec as I later found. If **ANY** tables are going to be related to tables in a different database - you won't be able to run certain queries against. For example, in create table - you won't be able to create a foreign key to a table in a different db. The key is to think of each db as a separate entity, even if you have template databases to start from - ultimately you'd still need to copy tables/indices/views to the working database.